# How can i use the Clockify API with Siri Shortcuts

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts, clockify

I want to use the **[Clockify API](https://clockify.me/developers-api)** together with Apple **Siri Shortcuts**. How can i make a request with a X-API-Key Authentication?

Here my try:
[Screenshot from Apple Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7f0j.png)

The result is: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "Variables/Set variable" component for your apikey in Siri Shortcuts. In your "Network" component paste you apikey directly into Headers section with "X-Api-Key" header name and it will work.

On screenshot provided you are trying to use URL path for getting user data and POST method configuration. It will not work. That URL path works only for GET requests. If you plan to use POST method see Clockify API documentation for correct URL paths.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your API key from web system:
   [image]
2. Get your workspace ID from web system URL
   [image]
3. Copy your project ID when edit it web system URL
   [image]
4. Add following shortcut to trigger timer to start for specific project using variables gathered in 1-3. In my case in Shortcuts app on MacOS I had to use TAB button to activate fields, because mouse is buggy in this Apple app.
   [image]
5. For other projects just copy same Shortcut and change projectID
6. To stop projects, duplicate shortcut and us following config
   [image]

Get your user id with curl (can install from brew)

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -H "X-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY" -X GET https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/user
```

Probably also smart to stop previous timer before running next
[image]